Using lookup on collection to join the collection
I have 2 collection rooms and actualRooms on which i want to join them using lookup aggregator  here is the collections.
1.Rooms
[{
_id:665e0762a3bb96e240df170b,
bhavanName:"KKR",
noOfBedperRoom:2,
landmark:"Kolkata",
totalNoOfRooms:20,
rooms:Array (empty),
roomAmount:"0",
createdAt:2024-06-03T18:11:04.874+00:00,
__v:0
}]

2.actualRooms
[{
_id:665e0762a3bb96e240df170d,
roomNumber:1,
noOfBed:2,
availabel:true,
used:0
bookedFrom:"",
bookedTill:"",
bookerIds:Array (empty),
bhavanId:665e0762a3bb96e240df170b,
__v:0
}]

Query which i am running using express and mongoose. I am trying to join this table using _id from rooms and bhavanId from actualRooms but i am getting an empty array.
const roomData = await RoomModal.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "actualRooms",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "bhavanId",
          as: "rooms",
        },
      },
    ]);


That lookup stages is matching on number of rooms, not _id or bhavanId.

@joe review it now i have updated the question

Are the ids in same datatype? i.e. both in ObjectIds or both in Strings? Datatype mismatch is one of the common mistakes that cause empty lookup

That code seems to work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NV6vqdam-qC . As @ray noted, make sure the datatypes are consistent.

HI i have tried your solution on my machine nut still i am getting empty [] for rooms using aggregate

I was having typo issue for the collection name in "from" field of lookup
